# What might I do with the familiar conjured by Conjure Familiar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the Conjure Familiar spell for?

Sure the familiar looks neato, but may I treat it as I would a familiar in another game?  So far, it doesn't speak to me, it doesn't supply me with wishes, and it doesn't lead me on a quest.

Have I exhausted what I can do with a familiar after I've successfully conjured it, or is there more to it than meets the eye?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A familiar is just a minion. It's only purpose is to attack enemies, and will vanish after 60 seconds. It is possible to use a familiar to level up your combat skills by attacking it, but other than that, it just attacks enemies.

Comment: +1. To be fair, this is a poorly named spell since it goes entirely counter to fantasy tropes.

Comment: In previous TES games, you could soul trap your familiars and kill them for easy soul gem fodder.  I don't know if that's possible in this version or not though.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried it out this morning, and the little guy went to town on a skeever.  I guess in all my previous summons of my familiar I hadn't been anywhere near an enemy.

Comment: @agent86: soultrapping your own conjures was made impossible in Skyrim. It 'resists capture'.